# ¿Como puedo "bindear" un ObservableCollection a varias vistas y mantenerla sincronizada entre las mismas? WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Necesito bindear un `ObservableCollection` a varias vistas y que dicha lista se mantenga sincronizada entre todas las vistas, en caso de modificar la lista (agregar, remover o actualizar un valor en dicha lista) el cambio se replique para todas las vistas.

Answer (score 1):

Si cuando dices 'otras vistas' te refieres a ventanas o elementos que no estan en el mismo formulario, entonces lo que puedes hacer es que al crear la lista, le envies por el constructor a cada vista la lista observable y bindiar la lista a su respectivos elementos en cada vista.

```
ObservableCollection<string> nombres = new ObservableCollection<string>();
Vista1 vista1 = new Vista1(nombres);
Vista2 vista2 = new Vista2(nombres);
Vista3 vista3 = new Vista3(nombres);
```

Y en las vistas:

```
public partial class Vista1
{
  public Vista1(ObservableCollection<string> nombres)
  {
    InitializeComponents();
    NombresListView.ItemsSource = nombres;

  }
}
```

Y repites lo mismo para las otras vistas.

Lo que estaria pasando es que como le envias la misma referencia de la lista a cada vista, al agregar un elemento a la lista se ejecutaria el evento [CollectionChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653375(v=vs.110).aspx) en cada instancia de las vistas.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que puedo entender, lo que necesitas es sencillo:

1.- Tu modelo debe de Implementar INotifyPropertyChanged:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace MvvmLight4.Model
{
    public class MiClase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {


        private string _property1;

        public string Property1
        {
            get { return _property1; }
            set { _property1 = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }

        private string _property2;

        public string Property2
        {
            get { return _property2; }
            set { _property2 = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }


        public static IEnumerable<MiClase> GenerarObjetos()
        {
            return new List<MiClase>()
            {
                new MiClase { Property1 = "1-P1", Property2 = "1-P2"  },
                new MiClase { Property1 = "2-P1", Property2 = "2-P2"  }
            };
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

2.- Crearte una propiedad de tipo ObsrevableCollection en el ViewModel:

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;
using MvvmLight4.Model;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace MvvmLight4.ViewModel
{

    public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {


        public MainViewModel(IDataService dataService)
        {
            Datos = new ObservableCollection<MiClase>(MiClase.GenerarObjetos());
        }



        private ObservableCollection<MiClase> _datos;

        public ObservableCollection<MiClase> Datos
        {
            get { return _datos; }
            set { _datos = value; RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Datos)); }
        }

    }
}
```

3.- La vínculas en tu vista a los controles que tu quieras:

```
    <TextBlock FontSize="36"
               FontWeight="Bold"
               Foreground="Purple"
               Text="{Binding WelcomeTitle}"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
               TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="362,94,361,82" Grid.Row="1" />
    <DataGrid Grid.Row="0" AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Datos}" />
    <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Datos}" />
    <DataGrid Grid.Row="2" AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Datos}" />
</Grid>
```

Y Funcionando sin problemas.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero no resuelve mi problematica...tu propuesta trabaja sobre la misma vista, en múltiples Datagrid. Pero yo necesito utilizar 1 misma lista en varias vistas diferentes.

Comment: Según lo que me comentas, creo que tu observablecollection, debería de estar en una clase estática o en un singleton, y bincular los contextos (ItensSource) de los controles huéspedes de cada vista a la clase estática o al singleton.

Comment: Eso si tiene un poco mas de sentido y aunque creo haberlo probado, no se si resultaría optimo el hacerlo estático ya que como mencione en la pregunta inicial, necesito que se pueda: ** modificar la lista (agregar, remover o actualizar un valor en dicha lista) el cambio se replique para todas las vistas.**

Answer (score 0):

Si funciona si, te cuento como lo he hecho:

De primeras he creado una clase singleton con una ObservableCollection:

```
public class Singleton : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private static Singleton instance = null;


    private ObservableCollection<MiClase> _lista = new ObservableCollection<MiClase>();

    public ObservableCollection<MiClase> Lista
    {
        get { return _lista; }
        set { _lista = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }



    private Singleton()
    {
    }

    public static Singleton Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                instance = new Singleton();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }



    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Y después he creado 2 ViewModel, con una propiedad ObservableCollection igual, pero modificando su Get, así:

```
public class ViewModel1 : INotifyPropertyChanged
{


    private ObservableCollection<MiClase> _listaPantalla1;

    public ObservableCollection<MiClase> ListaPantalla1
    {
        get
        {
            return Singleton.Instance.Lista;
        }
        set { _listaPantalla1 = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }


    public ViewModel1()
    {
        ListaPantalla1.Add(new MiClase { Property1 = "Uno Pantalla1", Property2 = "Uno Pantalla1" });
    }



    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

}

public class ViewModel2 : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private ObservableCollection<MiClase> _listaPantalla2;

    public ObservableCollection<MiClase> ListaPantalla2
    {
        get
        {
            return Singleton.Instance.Lista;
        }
        set { _listaPantalla2 = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }


    public ViewModel2()
    {
        ListaPantalla2.Add(new MiClase { Property1 = "Uno Pantalla2", Property2 = "Uno Pantalla2" });
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Despues he vinculado las vistas con sus ViewModels y he añadido un DataGrid a cada una y he vicunculado su ItemSource a las propiedades lista de sus respectivos ViewModels, y funciona, si modifico algo en una se ve reflejado en la otra y viceversa.

Si te hace falta el código dímelo y te pongo un enlace de descarga.

Espero que te ayude.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes colocar la lista en un ViewModel y el ViewModel instancearlo en el App.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>                        
        <!-- ViewModels -->
        <vm:MyViewModel                   x:Key="MyVM" />
    </ResourceDictionary> 
</Application.Resources>
```

Con eso tienes la colección centralizada y como el App.xaml está por sobre todas las demás clases no necesitas más que llamarlo, puedes definirlo en tus clases como propiedad

```
private ObservableCollection<MiClase> _myVM;

public ObservableCollection<MiClase> MyVM
        {
            get { return _myVM; }
            set { _myVM= value; }
}
```

Y luego llamarlo directamente en el constructor de cada clase donde necesites usarlo o asignarlo como ItemSource o DataContext donde lo quieras visualizar:

```
MyVM = (ObservableCollection<MiClas>)FindResource("MyVM");
```

Espero te haya servido, un saludo.